# ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

Tags: java, xml, oracle, hibernate, maven

I want to use hibernate in my maven project. I added hibernate.cfg.xml and hibernate.reveng.xml to resources, also added hibernate and oracle drivers to pom.xml, but the problem is that it doesn't recognize the oracle driver class.

Here is the output

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.moshtagh.core.util.db.DataBase.<clinit>(DataBase.java:51)
at com.narmafzarsazan.peymane.model.AuthenticateModel.getWebUserByUserNameAndPassword(AuthenticateModel.java:35)
at com.narmafzarsazan.peymane.rs.AuthenticateRS.getText(AuthenticateRS.java:71)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: 
org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: 
HHH010003: JDBC Driver class not found: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
at org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider.configure(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:147)
    at 

  org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at 

  org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178)
    at 

  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(Jd
    bcServicesImpl.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1885)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843)
    at com.moshtagh.core.util.db.DataBase.<clinit>(DataBase.java:46)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:245)
    at org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider.configure(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:144)
    ... 66 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:230)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:242)
    ... 67 more
```

and pom.xml file

```
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- for JPA, use hibernate-entitymanager instead of hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- optional -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20090211</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.21</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ojdbc7.jar example -->
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.0</version>
    </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>jboss</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-transaction</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
```

and hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.3:1521:orclutf8</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">TAMS</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">oracle110</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">150</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <!--    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>-->
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
```

if you know this error, help me through this.

thx

Comment: Don't see an oracle driver JAR in your dependencies. I notice you're using this [wrapper (?) project from GitHub](https://github.com/NoraUi/ojdbc7), but I don't see that automagically pulling in the Oracle JAR.

Comment: What kind of IDE did you use?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I edit my file, actually the error is the same.

Comment: @lihongxu I used netbeans ide

Comment: You need to add oracle JDBC driver in your class path.

So first download it, then add it your class path.-- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html

Comment: @VikasSuryawanshi what is the classpath for maven projects? I added java libs classpath in environment variables.

Comment: you are getting this error because the compiler not able to find the Odbc class it means it is not loading jar file for the same so please check once properly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ensure to add your ojdbc7.jar to your classpath.

```
1.Add ojdbc7.jar to TOMCAT_HOME/lib
2.Add ojdbc7.jar to JAVA_HOME/jre/lib
3.Trying with ojdbc6.jar if it still not works
```

Comment: I added that, still the same problem

Comment: @mhtb  Put the jar under the WEB-INF/lib directory.

Comment: I added it, but it did not change

Comment: Finally! Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The OJDBC driver is not available in maven central which is why maven fails to find it. 
You need to download it manually from the oracle homepage.

Then you can either deploy it to a self hosted maven repository and add that repository to your pom or just add the jar file directly to your classpath.

Comment: actually I installed it manually, but the driver class was not found