# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

Tags: eclipse, oracle, hibernate, maven

I am using Hibernate with oracle first time. I don't know why it is not working, tried every possible thing to make it work, but not able to find correct answer. 
Below is my hibernate.cfg.xml file

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">****</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">SYSTEM</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">none</property>
        <mapping resource="mapping.hbm.xml" /> 
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

password is which I gave at the time I install the oracle in my system.

oracle pom dependency:

````
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
    <version>12.2.0.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency> ```
Have already added the ojdbc7 in maven through command prompt.
Or should I switch the database ? will that help me ?
````

Comment: Please check the below URL for the solution of this problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44538440/classnotfoundexception-oracle-jdbc-oracledriver/44539017